# Can't find ColorStateList from drawable resource ID only on Android Nougat

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat

I have found this error in my Crashlytics, and it seems like it's only crashing for users with preview version of Android Nougat.

App crashes on startup (Main Activity).

**Stacktrace**

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.my.domain/com.my.domain.activities.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Can't find ColorStateList from drawable resource ID #0x7f020057
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
Caused by android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Can't find ColorStateList from drawable resource ID #0x7f020057
   at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadColorStateList(ResourcesImpl.java:840)
   at android.content.res.Resources.loadColorStateList(Resources.java:998)
   at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:447)
   at android.app.Activity.onApplyThemeResource(Activity.java:4039)
   at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.initializeTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:198)
   at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.setTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:140)
   at android.app.Activity.setTheme(Activity.java:4009)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setTheme(AppCompatActivity.java:90)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2592)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

It looks like Android Nougat no longer supports some kind of system colors that I'm using in my app? But I don't know exactly how to fix it.

**Edit**

So I found the resource with ID 0x7f020057 in my **R** file and this is it:

> public static final int background_splash_gradient=0x7f020057;

I checked where I am using it and here it is:

```
<style name="StartingWindowTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_splash_gradient</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@drawable/background_splash_gradient</item>
</style>
```

And this is the *background_splash_gradiend* xml file:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<gradient
    android:angle="135"
    android:endColor="#00d49e"
    android:startColor="#00bcd4"/>

</shape>
```

I still don't know why this is causing issues on Nougat. I tried removing the "StartingWindowTheme" style and app now works, it no longer crashes. But I need a better fix than that.

**Edit 2**

So I tried to remove this line:

```
<item name="android:colorBackground">@drawable/background_splash_gradient</item>
```

And it works. Seems like `android:colorBackground` is the issue.

**TEMPORARY FIX**

Since the problem is in the line mentioned above, only on Nougat, I have created a `values-v24` folder and removed the line there. App works on Nougat now, but I would appreciate a better solution.

Comment: do you use anything from `android.R.color`?

Comment: Hm, I am actually not sure, I just did a global search for "android.R.color" and it didn't find anything. Assuming that this is the issue, what would be the solution?

Comment: Actually, yes, it seems like I'm using it in xml. I am using "@android:color/transparent"

Comment: Actually now that you mention it, you might be able to check your `R` file and see the variable name for `0x7f020057` (which is `2130837591`)

Comment: I'd have some trouble on my hands if this really stopped working though, I've been using `android.R.color.white` and `android.R.color.transparent` and `android.R.color.black` a lot.

Comment: So I searched for resource 0x7f020057 in my R file and I found out **where** the problem is, but I still don't know **why** there is a problem. Please see my edited question.

Comment: What happens if you keep `windowBackground` but remove `colorBackground`?

Comment: It works, seems like windowBackground is the issue.

Comment: So I guess `colorBackground` was the issue? Glad to hear you found a solution.

Comment: From the looks of it, this is an Android Nougat bug. I have opened an issue here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=218945&thanks=218945&ts=1470083662

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found where the problem was and how to fix it. Here's the solution, I'll keep it simple.

This line was causing the problem:

```
<item name="android:colorBackground">@drawable/background_splash_gradient</item>
```

Turns out you can't set drawable as a colorBackground in XML, so it works after removing this line.

The reason this only crashed on Nougat is because this was possible in earlier versions.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that [according with the Android issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37114374), this is Working As Intended.

`android:colorBackground` expects a color not a drawable.