# How to set status bar background as gradient color or a drawable in Android?

Tags: android, drawable, gradient, statusbar

I want to set status bar background as gradient theme also  status bar and action bar color should same gradient drawable, as per documentation  we can set color to status bar in API level 21 and above by using

```xml
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
```

But I am searching something like

```xml
<item name="android:statusBarDrawable">@drawable/myDrawable</item>
```

I have seen example that use

```xml
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">false</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">false</item>
```

But in that case status bar and action bar overlap (use `fitSystemWindow=true` but still not solved) also try with https://github.com/jgilfelt/SystemBarTint this library but still no luck.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

[image]For some one who want to set gradient color to status bar background you can use following method in your activity before setContentView()

For Java

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public static void setStatusBarGradiant(Activity activity) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        Window window = activity.getWindow();
        Drawable background = activity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.gradient_theme);
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        
        window.setStatusBarColor(activity.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
        window.setNavigationBarColor(activity.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
        window.setBackgroundDrawable(background);
    }
}
```

For Kotlin

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
fun setStatusBarGradiant(activity: Activity) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        val window: Window = activity.window
        val background =ContextCompat.getDrawable(activity, R.drawable.gradient_theme)
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS)
        
        window.statusBarColor = ContextCompat.getColor(activity,android.R.color.transparent)
        window.navigationBarColor = ContextCompat.getColor(activity,android.R.color.transparent)
        window.setBackgroundDrawable(background)
    }
}
```

Thanks every one for your help

**EDIT**

If the above code don't work, try to add this in your `styles.xml`:

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

If you want to override status bar with your view then use `window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);`

Comment: This answer is not working. Is there any thing else we need to do in style for getting gradient effect in status bar?

Comment: show me what you have did !! May be check your device version code if it is below  Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP means 21 or below 21 if yes than this feature is not work with that device

Comment: i did implement your code as you said

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setStatusBarGradiant(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);
}

Comment: so what is issue means any error or just not working

Comment: @VívêkBåräì can you tell me the way you found? I'm not able to use this. It doesn't work for me.

Comment: @ArdaÇebi i have posted answer you may check

Comment: @VívêkBåräì Thanks!

Comment: don't know why its not working for both of u ? did you check on LOLLIPOP and above ?? It should work  this is the real screenshot of my app

Comment: work here, but only after add on styles.xml the following code: 
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

Comment: did you call above method before setContentView method of the activity ? show us your code @VindhyaPratapSingh

Comment: Not Working, in api 29

Comment: This works, just adding that this also sets your navigation bar to the gradient, while the OP asked only for status bar. Comment out the line if you dont want that

Answer (score 11):

an extension to the sushant's answer since getColor is deprecated and in kotlin language.

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
fun backGroundColor() {
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS)
    window.statusBarColor = ContextCompat.getColor(this, android.R.color.transparent)
    window.navigationBarColor = ContextCompat.getColor(this, android.R.color.transparent)
    window.setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.ic_drawable_vertical_background)
}
```

The idea is to make transparent status bar and setting a background to the whole window which will also cover the status bar in the same background.

Answer (score 10):

Here how you do it without any Java code,

Gradient drawable file `drawable/bg_toolbar.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:type="linear"
        android:angle="0"
        android:startColor="#11998e"
        android:endColor="#38ef7d" />
</shape>
```

add this in your `values/style.xml`

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/bg_toolbar</item>
<item name="toolbarStyle">@style/Widget.Toolbar</item>
<item name="android:statusBarColor">#00000000</item>
```

make a new file for your toolbar Gradient `values/toolbar.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Widget.Toolbar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
        <item name="contentInsetStart">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/bg_toolbar</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**Edit:** Add `background android:background="#ffffff"` in your Activity Layout file.

Answer (score 9):

Add this code in onCreate

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
android.graphics.drawable.Drawable background = MainActivity.this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.status);
getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(background);
```

Now add a file with name status in drawable folder and put this code

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item><!-- Edit hex colors as you like -->
<shape android:shape="rectangle" >
<gradient
android:angle="180"
android:endColor="#806AF8"
android:startColor="#F16EB5" />
</shape></item></layer-list>
```

Comment: just use the below line to get drawable. 
ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.status_bar_gradient)

Answer (score 4):

the answer of @sushant gosavi is right but it does not work on `DrawerLayout` unless you do the following in `DrawerLayout`.

```xml
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_navigation"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_navigation"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

You must change to false `android:fitsSystemWindows="false"` in `DrawerLayout` and set it to true in the childs

Answer (score 2):

Adding the following two lines helped me:

```
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);
```

Comment: This is for sending toolbar up (under the status bar )

Comment: @HamedJaliliani so how can I add a gradient background color to statusbar without removing the navigation bar ?

Answer (score 1):

**Step1:** Create a status bar class like below

```
public class StatusBarView extends View
{
    private int mStatusBarHeight;

    public StatusBarView(Context context)
    {
        this(context, null);

    }

    public StatusBarView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        if( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
            setSystemUiVisibility(SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public WindowInsets onApplyWindowInsets(WindowInsets insets)
    {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
            mStatusBarHeight = insets.getSystemWindowInsetTop();
            return insets.consumeSystemWindowInsets();
        }
        return insets;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        setMeasuredDimension(MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec),mStatusBarHeight);
    }
}
```

**Step2:** create a drawable gradient like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:type="linear"
        android:angle="135"
        android:endColor="#F34D80"

        android:startColor="#FF5858"/><!--android:centerColor="#C12389"-->
</shape>
```

**Step3:** create a layout like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <YOURPACKAGENAME.StatusBarView
        android:id="@+id/status_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/toolbar_bg_gradient"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/toolbar_bg_gradient"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        app:subtitleTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Step4:** create a style for activity

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBarMain" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowEnableSplitTouch">false</item>
        <item name="android:splitMotionEvents">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds" tools:targetApi="lollipop">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="lollipop">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:colorForeground">@color/foreground_material_light</item>
        <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="actionModeStyle">@style/LywActionMode</item>
    </style>

<style name="LywActionMode" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.ActionMode">
        <item name="background">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="backgroundSplit">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: Should I create the class (step 1) as a separate file or copy that code to my Activity's class?

Comment: OK, understood that.

Comment: Should I do the same [create a new .xml file (layout)] or copy that code to my activity_main.xml file? (Step 3)

Comment: @ArdaÇebi You should copy that code there and its a example you can make changes as per requirements

Comment: Really, doesn't work. I've been trying different places and different forms to insert the code (after finding the real place of course just to make sure I can fix it).

Comment: code i gave you is completely working you can first create example of it.

Comment: @style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay  @style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay not found

Answer (score 0):

I used the answer on this link [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43405486/6120430)
and if you want to show action bar I added next code make it **transparent background**

```
final ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
    if (ab != null) {
        Drawable gradientBG = getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.bg_transperant);
        ab.setBackgroundDrawable(gradientBG);
    }
```

and then in bg_gradient.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">
       <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this

```
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/backfull</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>

    <item name="android:windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>

</style>

<style name="AppTheme2" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@drawable/backfull</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@android:color/white</item>>
    <item name="colorAccent">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@android:color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="ToolbarTheme" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/backfull</item>
    <item name="background">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="titleTextAppearance">@style/ToolbarTitleTheme</item>
    <item name="popupTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="theme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="ToolbarTitleTheme">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/holo_red_dark</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

the answer provided by sushant goswami is actually working fine, after wasting one day finally realized that the status bar color and the gradient start color both were same in my case,after changing gradient color to some color other than default status bar color it was working well

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin version. Based on sushant gosavi's answer

```kotlin
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
fun setBackgroundDrawableResource(window: Window, @DrawableRes drawableRes: Int) {
    val context = window.context
    val backgroundDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, drawableRes) ?: return
    val transparentColor = ContextCompat.getColor(context, android.R.color.transparent)
    window.apply {
        addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS)
        statusBarColor = transparentColor
        setBackgroundDrawable(backgroundDrawable)
    }
}
```