# how to set status bar with gradient drawable same as action bar?

Tags: android, gradient, drawable, statusbar

i have tried many ways but it overlaps toolbar and status bar.Also it gives back press bottom navigation default. 
i have added below code-

```
 @Override
  protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
  Window w = getWindow();  w.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);//allow window to extend outside of the screen.
            w.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);// override FLAG_FULLSCREEN and force the screen decorations (such as the status bar) to be shown.         w.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_ATTACHED_IN_DECOR);            w.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);           w.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);
        }
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }
```

[image]

Comment: are you using NoActionBarTheme and creating your own toolbar? or the other way around? The UI looks pretty good btw.

Comment: thanks for response,yes i am using custom toolbar and i have aaded drawble gradient file to toolbar background

Comment: @Prachi rane i have posted a code have look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/48556397/7609347

Answer (score 6):

Call this method before setContentView.

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public static void setStatusBarGradiant(Activity activity) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        Window window = activity.getWindow();
        Drawable background = activity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.gradient_theme);
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        window.setStatusBarColor(activity.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
        window.setNavigationBarColor(activity.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
        window.setBackgroundDrawable(background);
    }
}
```

Also make sure that you are using the theme `AppTheme.NoActionBar`. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43140039/10512459). If it doesn't work check the other answers to the question.

To hide the bottom navigation bar use this

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
// Hide both the navigation bar and the status bar.
// SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN is only available on Android 4.1 and higher, but as
// a general rule, you should design your app to hide the status bar whenever you
// hide the navigation bar.
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

Check [this](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/navigation#java) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for answer it works but not removing bottom bar

Comment: Which bottom bar are you talking about?

Comment: which is in grey color