# Instead of changing its activity app is going off

Tags: android

catGridAdapter adapter = new catGridAdapter(catList);
catGrid.setAdapter(adapter);

after putting these lines my app is not changing activity
but without these lines it is changing and not showing anything on it

**these are the logs**

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.android.quiz, PID: 20014
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class TextView
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class TextView
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Can't find ColorStateList from drawable resource ID #0x7f070091
at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadColorStateList(ResourcesImpl.java:1173)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadColorStateList(Resources.java:1066)
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColorStateList(TypedArray.java:541)
at android.widget.TextView.(TextView.java:1261)
at android.widget.TextView.(TextView.java:867)
at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.(AppCompatTextView.java:100)
at com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView.(MaterialTextView.java:93)
at com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView.(MaterialTextView.java:88)
at com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView.(MaterialTextView.java:83)
at com.google.android.material.theme.MaterialComponentsViewInflater.createTextView(MaterialComponentsViewInflater.java:61)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:115)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1551)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1602)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:817)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:775)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:908)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:869)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:521)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
at com.example.android.quiz.catGridAdapter.getView(catGridAdapter.java:40)
at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2472)
at android.widget.GridView.onMeasure(GridView.java:1065)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22406)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:958)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:685)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22406)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6842)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:146)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22406)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6842)
at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:490)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22406)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6842)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22406)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6842)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1514)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:806)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:685)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22406)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6842)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:907)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22406)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2597)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1606)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1879)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1488)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7182)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:935)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:747)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:677)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:921)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:192)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6759)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:556)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:875)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 20014 SIG: 9
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:7484', transport: 'socket'[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66cCM.png)

the adapter code is in image
[the code 0f  catGridAdapter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66cCM.png)

Comment: Can you provide some errors/logs for us to work with?

Comment: I have update logs

Comment: Would you be able to post some part of your `CatGridAdapter` code? It looks like the error might be line 40 of `catGridAdapter()` class

Comment: I had post catGridAdapter code .

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be something wrong with the view you're trying to inflate i.e. `R.layout.cat_item_layout`.

Theres a problem with `colorStateList` of some element you're possibly trying to set in that `cat_item_layout`.

I would advise you to check this answer and see if you're trying to set any `background color` or similar property (which may be unsupported) in a specific android version. Please check this answer and see if you're facing similar problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40575889/7892830